# Geometric intuition behind this chain homotopy

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Warning: using Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifols* notation in what follows.

My question has to do with the chain homotopy that appears in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifols* and Rotman's *Introduction to Algebraic Topology* proofs that the inclusion

$$C_\bullet^\mathcal{U}(X)\hookrightarrow C_\bullet(X)$$

Induces an isomorfism in singular homology

$$H_p^\mathcal{U}(X)\cong H_p(X)$$

For all $p\geq 0$. First, a series of definitions

> If $\alpha=A(v_0,\dots,v_p)$ is an affine singular $p-$simplex in some convex set $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $w$ is any point in $K$, we define an affine singular $(p+1)-$simplex $w*\alpha$ called **the cone on $\alpha$ from $w$** by:
>
> $$w*\alpha=w*A(v_0,\dots,v_p)=A(w,v_0,\dots,v_p)$$
>
> And we extend this operator to affine chains by linearity: $w*\big(\sum_{i\in I}n_i\alpha_i\big)=\sum_{i\in I}n_i(w*\alpha_i)$

An important formula is proved in both references, regarding the relationship between the boundary and cone operators

> If $c$ is an affine chain, then
>
> $$\partial(w*c)=c-w*\partial c$$

It is obvious that if $c$ is a cycle, the last formula becomes $\partial(w*c)=c$, and Rotman calls this **an intrgration formula**.

Afterwards, both authors define an operator $s$ that sends affine $p-$chains into affine $p-$chains, called **the barycentric subdivision operator**. This is done by induction:

> For $p=0$, $s=\text{Id}$
>
> Suppose that $s$ has been defined for some $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, for any affine $(p+1)-$simplex $\alpha:\Delta_p\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ we set
>
> $$s\alpha=\alpha(b_p)*s\partial\alpha$$
>
> Where $b_p$ is the **barycentre** of the standard singular simplex $\Delta_p$, and we extend this operator to affine chains by linearity: $s\big(\sum_{i\in I}n_i\alpha_i\big)=\sum_{i\in I}n_is\alpha_i$

Now, to extend this operator to arbitrary singular chains, note that if $\sigma$ is a singular $p-$simplex in any space $X$, then $\sigma=\sigma_{\#}i_p$, where $i_p:\Delta_p\longrightarrow\Delta_p$ is the identity map considered as an affine singular $p-$simplex in $\Delta_p$, and $\sigma_\#:C_\bullet(\Delta_p)\longrightarrow C_\bullet(X)$ is the chain map obtained from the continuous map $\sigma$.

So the idea is that if we have a singular chain $c$, then applying sucesively the subdivision operator, we will obtain a chain homologous to $c$, but whose simplices have images all lying in elements of $\mathcal{U}$.

To prove this, we should find a chain homotopy between the identity and the subdivision operator, that is, a homomorphism $h:C_p(X)\longrightarrow C_{p+1}(X)$ such that

$$h\circ\partial+\partial\circ h=\text{Id}-s$$

But Lee and Rotman gives

$$h\sigma=\sigma_\#b_p*(i_p-si_p-h\partial i_p)$$

And extend to chains by linearity. However, I am struggling to understand what geometric intuirion is behind this intriguing formula. I tried to draw what $h$ looks like when $\sigma=\text{Id}_{\Delta_1}$, but it is really hard (impossible?) to imagine this acting on $2-$simplices

[image]

In contrast with the chain homotopy that appears in the proof of the homotopy axiom, this is really less intuitive, and relies heavily on what Rotman calls *the integration formula*.

So my questions are

- How should we understand geometrically this map $h$? What is the geometric intuition that allows us to choose this a a good chain homotopy for our purposes?
- How should we understand the formula $\partial(w*c)=c-w*\partial c$? What is the meaning of this equation geometrically speaking?
- How to come up with such a map in the first place? How has this theorem developed historically?

I understand perfectly both demonstrations, since the calculations are easy to follow; I am just concerned with how this map gives no intuition at first glance about the geometry involved.

Comment: Your PS is not needed : this is a greatly written question : there are precise questions, there's a motivation, and you show that you tried stuff : a model question for sure ! Just a note : I don't understand your definition of cone in the beginning : what does your notation $A(w,v_0,...,v_p)$ mean ? I mean, I know what cones are so I understand the rest but not sure about this

Comment: $A(v_0,\dots,v_p):\Delta_p\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is the only affine map that sends each $e_i=(0,\dots,1^{(i},\dots,0)$ to $v_i$, where the codomain is just a suitable Euclidean space.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. For your second question, did you try to draw what $w*c$ was, and what its boundary was ? Take $c$ to be a $1$-simplex at first, and then a $2$-simplex

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how that equation plays a role into the other stuff...

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of the formula for $h\sigma$ as a description of a subdivision of the simplicial cylinder $\sigma \times [0,1]$ as a simplicial complex.

The equation $h \circ \partial + \partial \circ h = \text{Id} - s$, when rewritten as 
$$\partial \circ h = \text{Id} - s - h \circ \partial
$$
can be understood geometrically like this:

1. The term $\text{Id}$ on the right hand side means that the simplex $\sigma \times 0$ on the bottom is not subdivided at all.
2. The term $-s$ on the right hand side means that we use the barycentric subdivision for the simplex $\sigma \times 1$ on the top, with barycenter $b_p \times \{1\}$.
3. The term $-h \circ \partial$ means that for each face of $\sigma$ of one dimension lower, the corresponding vertical side of $\sigma \times [0,1]$ is subdivided according to the inductively given formula for $h$ in one dimension lower.

And the term $\partial \circ h$ on the left hand side then gives us a clue for how to define $h$ by induction: assuming by induction that $h$ is defined in one dimension lower, use the right hande side and steps 1,2,3 to subdivide the boundary of $\sigma \times [0,1]$, and then figure out some clever way to subdivide the interior also, hopefully a way that can be described by some cute formula.

Let's do this when $\sigma$ is the 1-simplex $[0,1]$. First draw $\sigma \times [0,1] = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. The cute formula
$$h\sigma = \sigma_\# b_p * (i_p - s i_p - h \partial i_p)
$$
tells you to do this: draw lines going from the $b_p \times \{1\} = (1/2,1)$ point on the top side $[0,1] \times \{1\}$, to all the vertices on the other sides of the square. You'll get a triangulation of the square with three triangles: one with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1/2,1)$, another with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(1/2,1)$, and the third with vertices $(1,0),(1/2,1),(1,0)$.

Now let's do this when $\sigma$ is a 2-simplex. Picture $\sigma$ in the $xy$ plane of $xyz$ space. So $\sigma \times [0,1]$ is a triangular cylinder in $xyz$ space. The bottom $\sigma \times 0$ is left unsubdivided. The top $\sigma \times 1$ is given the barycentric subdivision, with $b_p \times \{1\}$ as the barycenter. The three vertical sides are, by induction, each triangulated into three 2-simplices as just discussed above. Now connect up $b_p \times 1$ with all the vertices on the other sides. You'll get a triangulation of $\sigma \times [0,1]$ into, let's see....... 7 tetrahedra? ... Nope, 10 tetrahedra.

Comment: This triangulation actually doesn't work... if you are interested, watch the answer to this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345501/geometric-intuition-behind-this-chain-homotopy?noredirect=1#comment865334_345501